# Knockout - Binding a computed from model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to use a computed observable to create a custom div ID (e.g. branch3).  However, anytime I attempt to bind the computed I get the "unable to parse bindings" error. I'm sure I could just go about doing this a different way, but I just don't understand why I can't use a computed here. I'm pretty sure I've seen it done.

Here is the jsfiddle I've been working on.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ricka/hawMW/1/)

```
var branchList   =[{"Id":1,"Latitude":40.2444400000,"Longitude":-111.6608300000,"StreetAddress":"1525 W 820 N","BranchName":"GPS","City":"Cityplacwe","State":"UT","Zip":"84601"},{"Id":2,"Latitude":40.2455550000,"Longitude":-111.6616100000,"StreetAddress":"123 N Center","BranchName":"GPS Branch 2","City":"Lehi","State":"UT","Zip":"84043"}];

//myMarkers = new Array();

var Branch = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
  self.Latitude = ko.observable(data.Latitude);
  self.Longitude = ko.observable(data.Id);
  self.BranchName = ko.observable(data.BranchName);
  self.StreetAddress = ko.observable(data.StreetAddress);
  self.City = ko.observable(data.City);
  self.State = ko.observable(data.State);
  self.Zip = ko.observable(data.Zip);
  this.DivId = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.Id();
  });
  //self.DivId = ko.computed({
  //  //Reading from object to field
  //  read: function () {
  //    return "branch" + self.Id();
  //  },
  //  //writing from field to object
  //  write: function (value) {

  //  }
//});

}

var BranchViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;

  //create knockout array
  self.branchArrayKO = ko.observableArray(branchList);
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: branchArrayKO">


<div data-bind="attr: {'id': DivId}">
  <p></p>
  <h2></h2>
  <ul>
    <li data-bind="text: Id"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: BranchName"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: StreetAddress"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your raw JavaScript array into an array of `Branch`es. One way to do this is to use `ko.utils.arrayMap` to iterate over each item in the list and create a new `Branch`:

```
var BranchViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    //create knockout array
    self.branchArrayKO = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(branchList, function(branch) {
        return new Branch(branch);
    }));
}
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hawMW/2/

Another alternative that might be useful is the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), which you can use to automate all or part of the mapping process.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't even thinking about the array